# problem with "String line = switch (a) in java loop. Cant implement cases

Tags: java, switch-expression

I made a program of tic-tac-toe. There is a problem on the line `String line = switch(a)` (*"illegal start of expression"*).

It is a window application of this game.

I have no idea how to fix this.

```
public void checkIfGameIsOver(){
    for (int a = 0; a < 8; a++) {
        String line = switch (a) {
            case 0 -> button1.getText() + button2.getText() + button3.getText();
            case 1 -> button4.getText() + button5.getText() + button6.getText();
            case 2 -> button7.getText() + button8.getText() + button9.getText();
            case 3 -> button1.getText() + button5.getText() + button9.getText();
            case 4 -> button3.getText() + button5.getText() + button7.getText();
            case 5 -> button1.getText() + button4.getText() + button7.getText();
            case 6 -> button2.getText() + button5.getText() + button8.getText();
            case 7 -> button3.getText() + button6.getText() + button9.getText();
            default -> null;
        };
```

I'm using Java version 1.8.0_231.

Comment: Java 8 doesn't support switch expressions.

Comment: You could replace that with chain of conditional expressions. It will lokk similar

Comment: ok thank you for your answear. J  have diferent version in my laptop, and diferent version on my work PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch expressions were introduced in Java 12 as a preview feature and formally made available in Java 13 ([JEP 354](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/354)). Given you're using Java 8, you cannot use switch expressions.

You either need to upgrade to a more recent Java version (e.g. Java 17), or use a switch *statement*.

That is:

```
public void checkIfGameIsOver(){
    for (int a = 0; a < 8; a++) {
        String line;
        switch (a) {
        case 0:
            line = button1.getText() + button2.getText() + button3.getText();
            break;
        case 1:
            line = button4.getText() + button5.getText() + button6.getText();
            break;
        case 2:
            line = button7.getText() + button8.getText() + button9.getText();
            break;
        case 3:
            line = button1.getText() + button5.getText() + button9.getText();
            break;
        case 4:
            line = button3.getText() + button5.getText() + button7.getText();
            break;
        case 5:
            line = button1.getText() + button4.getText() + button7.getText();
            break;
        case 6:
            line = button2.getText() + button5.getText() + button8.getText();
            break;
        case 7:
            line = button3.getText() + button6.getText() + button9.getText();
            break;
        default:
            line = null;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported in Java 8. However, you can replace that with conditional expressions that are supported in Java8 which will look very similar.

```
public void checkIfGameIsOver(){
    for (int a = 0; a < 8; a++) {
        String line = a==0 ? button1.getText() + button2.getText() + button3.getText() :
            a==1 ? button4.getText() + button5.getText() + button6.getText():
            a==2 ? button7.getText() + button8.getText() + button9.getText():
            a==3 ? button1.getText() + button5.getText() + button9.getText():
            a==4 ? button3.getText() + button5.getText() + button7.getText():
            a==5 ? button1.getText() + button4.getText() + button7.getText():
            a==6 ? button2.getText() + button5.getText() + button8.getText():
            a==7 ? button3.getText() + button6.getText() + button9.getText():
            null;
        };
```

With the disclaimer that `a==7` is optional as it is always true on last iteration

so it could be

```
public void checkIfGameIsOver(){
    for (int a = 0; a < 8; a++) {
        String line = a==0 ? button1.getText() + button2.getText() + button3.getText() :
            a==1 ? button4.getText() + button5.getText() + button6.getText():
            a==2 ? button7.getText() + button8.getText() + button9.getText():
            a==3 ? button1.getText() + button5.getText() + button9.getText():
            a==4 ? button3.getText() + button5.getText() + button7.getText():
            a==5 ? button1.getText() + button4.getText() + button7.getText():
            a==6 ? button2.getText() + button5.getText() + button8.getText():
            button3.getText() + button6.getText() + button9.getText();
        };
```

Comment: This will likely perform less than using a switch *statement*.

Answer (score -1):

#### First solution:

Declare `String line` first and then just set the value with the switch expression.

`case 0 -> line = /*getText*/`

#### Second solution:

Are you using any jdk with a smaller version than 13? Then that is the issue, due to switch **expressions** only being added in Java 13 and above

#### Side note

If you want to use `String line` outside of your for loop, you'd have to declare the variable outside of the for loop

Comment: Your first solution will not work, because the `case 0 ->` syntax was introduced together with switch expressions.